# Extending a storefront javascript class from a non Shopware plugin class

Tags: shopware

How can I import a javascript class from a Shopware plugin so i can extend the class? For Shopware javascript classes the files are located under `src` (for example `import Plugin from 'src/plugin-system/plugin.class';` but 3rd party plugins aren’t located there afaik.

```
import Class from 'myplugin/component/path/plugin';

export default class MyClass extends Class {

}
```

Current way of import is as follows but that should be accomplished cleaner.

```
import MyClass from '../../../../../../../../../vendor/store.shopware.com/myplugin/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/component/*********/**********.******';
```

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? If yes, please post an answer.

Comment: No, I don't think there is another possibility atm.